# Can a react-native App retrieve other native app's datas

Tags: android, react-native

I am starting to learn react-native and I need to answer to an essential question :

Is it possible to retrieve the time spent on the other apps by the user from my react-native app ? 
I've red that react-native JS was facing several limitations compared to Java. But still, is there a way to get datas from another native app ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In short. No. You can't now how long the user spends on other apps, doesn't matter if you are running a native or react-native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is currently no way to get data from another app. You're going to need either need to:

1. Create your own backend and aggregate data from the other app, then
   make requests to grab that data
2. If the other app uses a public API and it has the data that you need, you can just call that API in your current app

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks you so much for your advice